# Need regex for matching relative paths within the source of a javascript and html file content

Tags: regex

Need help from regex gurus. I need a regex pattern to match relative file paths within the source-code of Javascript files.

Must match only relative paths that have at least 1 or more / and a file extension.
Example paths in source:

SHOULD MATCH:

```
var p = "./path/to/file.jpg";
var paths ['/path/file.jpg', `./sample.jpg`]
```

ONLY needs to match after "|' up to last /.
So, from above paths, this is what the matched
groups should find:

```
"./path/to/"
"/path/"
"./"
```

I plan on using the regex to replace the relative paths so the source only points to the file.

SHOULD NOT MATCH ANY OF THESE THAT LOOK LIKE PATHS:

```
var mime = "text/html";
var reg = /some\-regex/;
var replaced = "test.match(/[a-z]/, "/")
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could work:

```
(?<=(['"`]))\.?\/.*?(?=\.[^.]+\1)
```

- `` (?<=(['"`])) `` - find an apostrophe, double-quote, or backtick and store it in capture group #1
- `\.?\/` - optional period followed by a slash
- `.*?` - loosely continue to capture everything
- `(?=\.[^.]+\1)` - close with a file extension and the same string opening as capture group #1

https://regex101.com/r/raEARx/1

Comment: Thanks for helping. Need it modified.
See:
https://regex101.com/r/raEARx/3

MODIFICATIONS NEEDED:
1. It should also match paths not starting with a /. Example: "foo/bar.png" and "../../foo/bar.png" is being ignored.

2. The matched groups should capture just the relative part of path, not includinf the quotes and filename. Example group should return something like:

```
a. "../some/path"
b. "/some/"
c. "./path/to/"
```

Comment: @jaysmith024 You can feel free to modify my example and fork your own regex101. If you share your attempt then I could steer you in the right direction.